Docker images and live-build
I'm working on constructing a live, non-persistant Debian system using live-build. In this system I need to have some containers set up and running but also need to keep the boot time of the system to a minimum.
I can install Docker in the chroot during the live-build process, but Docker seemingly cannot operate within a chroot environment, preventing images from being built and pulled. I can use skopeo to pull remote images and buildah to build local images, but I understand that these images must be tar'd and loaded into Docker (using docker load) prior to use. This presents a problem of course since Docker won't run during live-build (nor will dockerd). I could of course store the images on the live file system and load them at boot, however this will unacceptably add to the boot time of the system, so this isn't an option. I'm not sure if it's possible to manually copy the images to /var/lib/docker/overlay2.
Surely there's got to be a way to prepare the live system (using live-build) to just run the containers at boot without having to pull or load them?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks
